# After migrating material version 4 to 5 vendor.js files stopped to minify CSS

Tags: reactjs, user-interface, material-ui, bundle, webpack-5

After migrating material version 4 to 5 vendor.js files stopped to minify CSS. Before 5 version I used 4 version of material that time CSS minification was working fine. Is anyone have solution on this ? Thank you for help in advance.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.